# Display custom fields in variations product page WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I've created two custom fields in variations with the following code (Thanks Remi Corso):

functions.php

Add Variation Settings

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'variation_settings_fields', 10, 3 );
```

Save Variation Settings

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 2 );
```

Create new fields for variations

```
function variation_settings_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => '_pdf_ficha_tecnica[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
            'label'       => __( 'PDF FICHA TÉCNICA', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'placeholder' => 'http://',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'aqui', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_pdf_ficha_tecnica', true )
        )
    );  
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => '_pdf_ficha_caracteristicas[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
            'label'       => __( 'PDF FICHA CARACTERÍSTICAS', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'placeholder' => 'http://',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'aqui', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_pdf_ficha_caracteristicas', true )
        )
    );
}
```

Save new fields for variations

```
function save_variation_settings_fields( $post_id ) {
    $text_field = $_POST['_pdf_ficha_tecnica'][ $post_id ];
    if( ! empty( $text_field ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_pdf_ficha_tecnica', esc_attr( $text_field ) );
    }
    $text_field = $_POST['_pdf_ficha_caracteristicas'][ $post_id ];
    if( ! empty( $text_field ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_pdf_ficha_caracteristicas', esc_attr( $text_field ) );
    }
}
```

These custom fields store URLs and will be displayed as links `<a href>`. I looking to display these fields but I'm having a lot of trouble finding the right solution.

Can anyone guide me?
Should I focus on file "variable.php"?
And the JS?
Or can I render the fields by hooks?

Comment: In the comments on Remi's tutorial there is [this link](http://blueskysessions.com/2014/03/31/woocommerce-display-dynamic-content-per-the-selected-product-variation/) which might help.

Comment: where are you planning to display this fields?

Comment: Thank you for answering elgatheviking!
I had read this link. I am newbie the customization of WooCommerce and jQuery. I have not found an example of code that looks like what I want. Continuing with the search, thank you!

Comment: Thank you for answering Reigel!
My idea is to show the two custom fields when the user selects the variation, for example just below the description of the variation.
The problem I have jQuery to create the relationship, I'm confused.

Comment: It seems to show "variation description" was recently implemented since version 2.4 of WooCommerce. It must be for this reason that I can not find examples of code, the front-end Remi Corso proposing no longer works and is not available for review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code I created works perfectly. I am new to JS and I'm sure can be improved. I hope that will be helpful. To create Custom Fields reads the post of REMI.

Explanation: With "WC_Product Variable" object can display the Custom Fields of product variation,

To display these fields I used jquery, the contents of the span "sku" will be our reference as shown on the product page. This code in the "variations.php" file.

```
<?php

// With "WC_Product Variable" object I get the Custom Fields variations.

$product_id = $product->id;
$variation = new WC_Product_Variable( $product_id );
$arrvariations = $variation->get_children ();

// With foreach construct the div that will contain the Custom Fields

foreach ($arrvariations as $varid) {
    $cfvalone = get_post_meta( $varid, '_custom_field_one', true );
    $cfvaltwo = get_post_meta( $varid, '_custom_field_two', true );

// Check the Custom Fields are not empty

    if (!empty($cfvalone) or !empty($cfvaltwo) ) {

        $cfonecont = get_post_meta( $varid, '_custom_field_one', true );
        $cftwocont = get_post_meta( $varid, '_custom_field_two', true );
        $varsku = get_post_meta( $varid, '_sku', true );

// Built the DIV and embed SKU of the variation to be processed later by JS.
?>
    <div class="varskudiv" data-varskudiv="<? echo $varsku;?>" style="display:none;">
        <?php if (!empty($cfonecont)) {?>
            <a href="<? echo $cfonecont;?>">CUSTOM FIELD ONE</a>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if (!empty($cftwocont)) {?>
            <a href="<? echo $cftwocont;?>">CUSTOM FIELD TWO</a>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <? }}?>
    <br/>
<script>   
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    // As we will take the contents of SPAN "sku" to create the JS 
    //we must consider that this SPAN is complete once the screen is loaded.

    $(window).bind("load", function() {
    woosku = $(".sku").text();
    // Now we map the DIV we created "varskudiv" and load those values in an ARRAY
    wooarrsku = $('div.varskudiv').map(function(){
        return $(this).data('varskudiv');
    }).get();
    // Now we make loop, if the values match show the DIV.
    var indexsku;
    for (indexsku = 0; indexsku < wooarrsku.length; indexsku++) {
    if (woosku == wooarrsku[indexsku]) {
        $('.varskudiv[data-varskudiv="'+ woosku +'"]').css( "display", "inline-block" );
        }
    }
    });
    // Once loaded the screen, if the SPAN "sku" changes, start the process again and hide the previous DIV displayed.

    $('.sku').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
      woosku = $(".sku").text();
        wooarrsku = $('div.varskudiv').map(function(){
            return $(this).data('varskudiv');
        }).get();
        var indexsku;
        for (indexsku = 0; indexsku < wooarrsku.length; indexsku++) {
        if (woosku == wooarrsku[indexsku]) {
            $('.varskudiv[data-varskudiv="'+ woosku +'"]').css( "display", "inline-block" );
            }
        else {$('.varskudiv[data-varskudiv="'+ wooarrsku[indexsku] +'"]').css( "display", "none" );
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Remi update the code:
http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-custom-fields-for-variations/